# Modem is not being detected (Why I've to usb_modeswitch?)

Tags: networking, modem, trisquel

I am using Trisquel 7.0 LTS and mobile broadband (Net-Setter) to establish connection.

<sup>Following states (1-4) are showing different conditions/situations for clear understanding of problem.</sup>

### State-1:-

After Installation of Trisquel 7.0 LTS, Everything is working fine. My modem is detected as follows (`lsusb` output):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173 3G Modem (modem-mode)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And It is also detected by nm-applet or say by using `nmcli` as follows:

```
$ nmcli dev list
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ttyUSB2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           gsm
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         HUAWEI Technology
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        HUAWEI Mobile
```

---

### State-2:-

<s>But</s> I <s>recently</s> ran an [installation script](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9638329/) from Mobile Partner, which did not properly install, and hence I also ran the [Un-installation script](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9638338/) And Unfortunately, in spite of uninstallation, now my modem isn't working (detecting properly).

There is now a change in detection and new (current) output by `lsusb` is:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Here you can see the difference that is-
**Ealier:**

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173 3G Modem (modem-mode)

**And Now:**

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)

**And now the modem isn't detected in nm-applet (nor listed by nmcli).**

So, How can I reset settings to default because default Trisquel has no problem with my device. In other words which files are affected by this new behavior and How do I revert to Earlier condition ? (Otherwise I have to re-install my whole OS!)

---

### State3:-

I've written a file named 12d1:1446 under `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/` which is:

```
DefaultVendor= 0x12d1 
DefaultProduct=0x1446

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

And I run this by command:

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1\:1446
```

Which works fine and cause `lsusb` changed

**From:**

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)

**Back To:**

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173 3G Modem (modem-mode)

**And hence it will be detected by network-manager ; I will be able to connect.**

---

### State-4:<sup>(Following to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176723/66803))</sup>-

I've written file named `99-mymodem.rules` under `/etc/rules.d` containing:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1446", RUN+="/home/pandya/usbmode"
```

And `/home/pandya/usbmode` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1\:1446
```

Hence, When I plugged in my modem, `99-mymodem.rules` runs `/home/pandya/usbmode` and I managed to detect my modem as:

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173 3G Modem (modem-mode)

**Ultimately I can successfully connect modem by network-manager (`nm-applet`).**

---

### Conclusion:-

However, current condition (**State-4**) is alternatively what I'm looking for but not Exactly (**State-1**) because we are passing through udev-rule and usb-modeswitch every time when modem is plugged-in.

In other words **Why I have to `usb_modeswitch` Now?** (Earlier no necessary, Also If I boot from Live DVD and choose Try OS without installing, modem is working fine without manually `usb_modeswitch`).

Therefore (since I've written this question) My aim is to revert to **State-1**.

Comment: @don_crissti I've attached scripts at the last of the post.

Comment: 1. Does your device belong to your ISP/Wireless Company?  Without using the USB modeswitch Script, do you have a PPPoE Daemon, such as `pppd`?

Comment: AFAIK all this is to be handled by udev and I think it's `modemmanager` that's supposed to install udev rules. Have you filed a bug / feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Last (Ultimately) I've found out what cause problem with automatic usb_mode switching.

The file [`40-usb_modeswitch.rules`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9671544/) under `/lib/udev/rules.d` contains:

```
# Huawei, newer modems
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1446", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

So, My modem must be automatically `usb_modeswitch` by `40-usb_modeswitch.rules`.

But the problem is that `/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch` & `/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher` not set `chmod +x` (Allow to execute file). Probably installation script (attached in question) had modified attribute.

While manually `sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1\:1446` (explained in question) I `sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch` **But `/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher` still not have execution permission.**

So Now I've just `sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher` and I almost Done!

After that I removed all manual switching process stated in **State-4** (see question) and Now my modem successfully detected as:

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173 3G Modem (modem-mode)

<sup>In other words `40-usb_modeswitch.rules` working fine.</sup>

Finally I reverted to **State-1**. [SOLVED]

Comment: Though this looks encouraging, I must say that I am confronted with the same problem, but on my system both files have the executable bit set - therefore I conclude that there must be other underlying contributing factors.

Answer (score 4):

Try udev rule wich launch a script every time you
plug the modem.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="UUUU", RUN+="/home/user/script.sh"
```

Replace XXXX and UUUU with vendor and id product,put rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-yourrule.rules and reboot or restart udev.
Must work

Comment: Yes, I tried it and is working fine. This seems alternative permanent solution but not actually because we manually passing through 1.udev rules and 2. usb_modeswitch by auto script(s) every time at plugged in. The perfect solution is to revert to default condition as explained in question. Any way thank-you for udev suggestion (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that in configuration file `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf` you have set

```
DisableSwitching=0
```

Otherwise automatic mode switching is disabled globally.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that is already `DisableSwitching=0` in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf` !

Comment: Your Idea of automatic mode switching helps me to troubleshoot my problem and I found [solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177369/66803). Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the same problem and the accepted solution did not work for me. If you have a Raspbian distro, there is a known bug discussed here: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/47.

The solution is:

1. edit `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`
2. edit `ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="08", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"`, by changing `'%b/%k'` to `'%k'`.

Tested on Raspbian 8 with Huawei EC315.